# How to loop through the following data (js)

Tags: javascript

I want to change this code so that I have a loop in a convenient and smarter way, the code runs on some website and it says that it "enters a link and exits from it"
So far I've done that in and out, how do I make it look more practical?

This script can identify certain areas of the site:

```
const element = document.getElementById("season");
const nodes = element.getElementsByTagName("li");


const element2 = document.getElementById("episode");
const nodes2 = element.getElementsByTagName("li");
```

This script makes a loop in an intelligent way according to parameters that I define in advance (now I don't want to define in advance but that it will automatically take this part, that if the site has 3 seasons and each season has 5 episodes it will display it in the following way:)

```
<script>
$video_number = '6586';
$season = '1';



let text = "";

for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    text += `'https://www.test.com/watch/${$video_number}/season/${$season}/episode/`+i+"',<br>";
  }
  
</script>
```

This is the final result I want to reach, I tried a lot of things but I can't succeed:

```
</script>
var allURL = [
  'https://www.test.com/watch/6586/season/1/episode/1',
  'https://www.test.com/watch/6586/season/1/episode/2',
  'https://www.test.com/watch/6586/season/1/episode/3',
  'https://www.test.com/watch/6586/season/1/episode/4',
  'https://www.test.com/watch/6586/season/2/episode/1',
  'https://www.test.com/watch/6586/season/2/episode/2',
  'https://www.test.com/watch/6586/season/2/episode/3',
  'https://www.test.com/watch/6586/season/2/episode/4',
  ];



</script>
```

My attempts - The result is good, but the number of seasons does not increase and does not multiply X times

```js
const element = document.getElementById("season");
const nodes = element.getElementsByTagName("li");

const element2 = document.getElementById("episode");
const nodes2 = element2.getElementsByTagName("li");

let text = "";

$prak = 'prak';
$video_numver = '6586';
$season = nodes.length - nodes.length + 1;
$episode = nodes2.length - nodes2.length + 1;

for (let i = 1; i <= $season; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j <= nodes2.length; j++) {
    text += `https://www.test.com/watch/${$prak}/season/${$season}/episode/${$episode++}` + "<br>";

  }
}

var allURL = [
  '<p id="demo"></p>',
];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="season">

  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>


</div>

<div id="episode">

  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>

</div>


<p id="demo"></p>
```

editing:
Here is the full code. I want it to scan the site every time, and open the chapter every time in a new tab and close it every time 30-35 seconds arrive

```
const seasons = document.querySelectorAll("#season li");
const episodes = document.querySelectorAll("#episode li");

let $prak = '5122',
  episodeLinks = [];

seasons.forEach(seasonLi => {
  const season = seasonLi.textContent.trim();
  episodes
    .forEach(episodeLi => {
      const episode = episodeLi.textContent.trim();
      const url = `https://www.test.com/watch/${$prak}/season/${season}/episode/${episode}`
      episodeLinks.push(`${url}`)
    });
});






var allURL = [
    episodeLinks.join(),

];



function showUrl(index) {
    index = index || 0;


    if (allURL.length === 0 || index < 0 || index >= allURL.length) {
        return;
    }

    // open the url
    var popup = window.open(allURL[index]);

    setTimeout(function() {
        popup.close();
        showUrl(index + 1);
    }, 5000);
}

showUrl(); // starts with the first url
```

Now he does the job well, but the problem is that every time he puts all the chapters in the URLS and I want him to put chapter by chapter after 30-35 seconds

Comment: _"the code runs on some website and it says that it "enters a link and exits from it""_ - What?

Comment: A string (`text += \`...\``) is not an array, and `allURL = [ '<p id="demo"></p>' ]; document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#examples

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML to show the issue - I added `$prak` to the code

Comment: @Andreas
I didn't want to reveal all the source code simply, but there is a continuation of this code, so what I'm trying to do is simply make it look like this:
'https://www.test.com/watch/6586/season/1/episode/1',
  'https://www.test.com/watch/6586/season/1/episode/2',

'https://www.test.com/watch/6586/season/2/episode/1',
  'https://www.test.com/watch/6586/season/2/episode/2',

Answer (score 0):

this should do what you want

Note I wrapped the episodes in the ULs of the seasons

```js
const seasons = document.querySelectorAll("#seasons>li");

let $prak = 'prak',
  $video_numver = '6586',
  episodeLinks = [],
  allURL = [];

seasons.forEach(seasonLi => {
  const season = seasonLi.querySelector("h3").textContent.trim();
  const episodes = seasonLi.querySelectorAll(".episode li");
  episodes
    .forEach(episodeLi => {
      const episode = episodeLi.textContent.trim();
      const url = `https://www.test.com/watch/${$prak}/season/${season}/episode/${episode}`
      allURL.push(url);
      //      episodeLinks.push(`<a href="${url}">${season.toUpperCase()}${episode.toUpperCase()}`)
    });
});

//document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = episodeLinks.join("<br/>")
// console.log(allURL)
let cnt = 0;
const runLength = 40; // minutes
let popup;
const run = () => {
  if (cnt >= allURL.length) return; // stop
 demo.innerHTML = `Playing ${cnt+1}: ${allURL[cnt]}`
  if (popup) popup.close();
  popup = window.open(allURL[cnt],"_blank");
  setTimeout(run,runLength*60*60*1000)
};
run(); // open the first
```

```html
<ul id="seasons">
  <li>
    <h3>s1</h3>
    <ul class="episode">
      <li>e1</li>
      <li>e2</li>
      <li>e3</li>
      <li>e4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>s2</h3>
    <ul class="episode">
      <li>e1</li>
      <li>e2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>s3</h3>
    <ul class="episode">
      <li>e1</li>
      <li>e2</li>
      <li>e3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>



<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Really really close!
Oh, you surprised me

How do I make every link go into this tab:
```
    var allURL = [
        'episodeLinks.join',
    ];```

Comment: See updated code.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me a lot, but it's not close to what I wanted, I wanted the screen to open every time and close after 40 seconds and go to the next link like that until the season + episodes are over.
And if the second season has fewer episodes than the first season? It's not 100 percent code like I wanted but pretty close.

Comment: I can only code what I am given to look at. Also "open every time?" Open from where? You want a new window to open?

Comment: I edited the question.
Is it possible?

Comment: See update. It will not work here because of the sandboxing, but if the browser will allow the popup (you may have to click something for the first) then it should work